# How to better setup production env settings for a Laravel project?

Tags: php, heroku, laravel-5, production-environment

As stated in the documentation, Laravel 5 uses a *cool* system called DotEnv. It enables us to configure all sorts of environment variables which will be available inside the project. As it may contain keys, it should be ignored in the source code.

Also, as its name is default, each machine/developer should have its own `.env` file.
Here comes the trouble: first, this is a private project. So I don't really mind stashing keys in the repository. Second, from other frameworks (Symfony? Yii?), I'm used to having separate settings for prod/stg/dev environments. But as the file is unique, this is not possible. Finally, I didn't want to mess with the production machine.

What's the best way to set those things up?

Comment: Clarifying about my environment: I'm using Heroku. The way I managed to get my env vars was using its console config vars, but that's far from desirable: any time I add something to .env I'll have to change it in Heroku as well? :(

Comment: most of developer add `.env` file to .`gitignore` file, so your configuration will not share to any one through repository. to handle these configuration you can use direct ftp like source.

Comment: Have you read my entire question, Safoor?

Comment: yeah, read the entire question and then giving you suggestion to handle system information as per environment...

Answer (score 0):

It's typical to exclude the `.env` file from your repository using a [`.gitignore`](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) file so that they may be configured differently for different environments.

You can create multiple `.env` files and manually upload them to your staging/testing/production environments. You would only need to do this once and change your settings depending on your environment.

Once in place, future deployments from your repository will not deploy your `.env` files and your environments will have separate configurations.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it implies an additional step for deployment - a manual one! And there's no place to store those settings, unless you create it. Finally, it touches what I said before: whenever I need to make a change to that file I'll have to remember to upload the change by hand to my server.

Comment: It creates a manual step, but this is part of the environment setup. Once I setup hosting for my staging/testing environments, I simply deploy all files and then create a .env file. I'd never have to do that again. I consider it a part of the hosting setup.

Comment: Yes you would have to change these settings manually, but since they are environment specific, they typically do not change once configured. What kind of changes/additions do you anticipate you will be making? If you are changing them often I'm curious to know what you might be storing in them.

Comment: Sadly this manual step doesn't fit very well with modern, automated deploy systems - such as using Git, or Heroku (my case). I don't consider this a server setting, but application information. As such, it would go together with the rest of the code.

Comment: Regarding what's going to change, I won't be storing weird stuff there. But it's subject to change every once in a while, like for configuring a new integration. And as with everything that happens only once in a while, it's easy to forget that step. In a day you include the new password in the .env file. A week later your work is done and you git deploy... And can't understand why you application crashed. Oh, you have to enter your host and manually edit that .env file ad well. Creepy.

Comment: Plus: there are a lot of production envs where you don't have access to the filesystem, or your code state is reset to the new git commit. And then all these setting have to be done differently.

Comment: I understand your concerns, but this would always be the the case when excluding these files from your repo and deployments. However, if your .env files require extra values, this could be updated in advance once you know that the extra values will be required. Without trying to sound rude, perhaps the issue is in going live with an update and the checks prior to deployment so you don't forget? I've used this method successfully for many many projects, Laravel and other application, the idea being that the configuration is deployment specific and separate from the code base.

Comment: To my knowledge this is a fairly standard approach, I'm not saying it's without problems. Perhaps somebody can offer another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Years passed and after some more experience, I can still say both approaches (ignored and non-ignored) env files have their good points.

The best approach on Laravel, for private projects, is to keep the shared keys in `.env.example`, together with sane defaults (such as `APP_ENV=prod` or `APP_DEBUG=false`) and leave to the developer installing the project the task to configure some of those variables, and those that are empty (i.e. logging channels or personal keys).